# checking bits in an NSData object

Tags: objective-c, c, byte, bit

how do i check if bits 0-6 in an NSData object which is `0x0001` are equal to 1?

My code

```
const char *byte = [dataObject bytes];
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    char n = byte[i];
    char buffer[9];
    buffer[8] = 0; //for null
    int j = 8;
    while(j > 0)
    {
        if(n & 0x01)
        {
            buffer[--j] = '1';

            //a bit is equal to 1 from my understanding
        } else
        {
            buffer[--j] = '0';
        }

        n >>= 1;
    }
}
```

says that bit 1 is a 1 which is clearly not true.

This runs on an iPhone which is a little Endian system

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65324/discussion-on-question-by-stackoverflew-checking-bits-in-an-nsdata-object).

Comment: `if (theByte & 0x01)`

Comment: i understand that for a byte, buy what about each one of the 8 individual bits for a byte?

Comment: @HotLicks please see my answer. I understood how to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27053910/1392515

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I ended up learning

```
const char *byte = [fixtureStatusBasic bytes]; //objective c, puts the 2 bytes into *byte
char n = byte[0]; //first byte is now called n
if(n & 0b00111111){ //AND the byte "n" with 6 least significant bits set to 1 to see if any of the 6 bits is set to 1

    //if this is true, and the program goes here, that means that one of the bits is set to 1

}
```

To see if bit 5 is set for example,

```
if(n & 0b00010000){

    //5th least significant byte is set to 1. 
}
```

thank you freenode.

Comment: `5` is not a valid binary digit. You mean `0b00010000`.